# Ionic 4 wrong height for ion-header and ion-footer when inside div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-component

I want to render some ionic components at the corner of a page, so I'm puting them inside a `div` with `fixed` position. Here's a sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      .container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10em;
        right: 2em;
        width: 30%;
        height: 30%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list color=danger>
          <ion-item color="secondary">Here</ion-item>
          <ion-item color="tertiary">Some</ion-item>
          <ion-item color="success">Content</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer>
        <ion-item color="warning">Footer</ion-item>
      </ion-footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The behavior I'm getting (`div` bounds shown in black):

[image: With header and footer]

When I remove `ion-header` and `ion-footer`:

[image: Without header and footer]

Think there's a bug in height calculation ([closest issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15799)).

I was hoping to reuse the header/footer logic, my content is scrollable in between.

Is there a workaround for this?

Any other web-component framework that implements this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Found a CSS solution, maybe not perfect, but works fine. First we find the `clientHeight` of header (`56px`) and footer (`48px`), then:

```html
<ion-content class="content">
```

```css
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 56px - 48px)
}
```

Result:

[image: result]